# Wordpress taxonomy terms archive template help

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I have custom post type Named Trips , Taxonomy > Destination , Region Activity Etc.

Region Terms are , Annapurna , Everest etc. Activity Terms are trek, hiking, tours etc.

I made an archive template called taxonomy-region.php to show all activities under Region. But it should show all activities inside region template categorically but its not working properly.

Here is my code for taxonomy-region.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Region
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */

get_header(); 
$custom_post_id = get_the_ID();
?>

<style type="text/css">
  section.country-bg {
    height: 555px;
}
</style>


<?php

$taxonomyslug = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
$term = get_queried_object();
$image = get_field('region_taxonomy_image', $term);

$description = get_field('region_taxonomy_description', $term);

?>
<section class="country-bg" style="background:url(<?php echo $image ?>);background-size:cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;"> 
</section>


<section class="main-sec">  
<div class="container">
<div class="main-wrap">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">

<div class="countryabout-text">
<?php
if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
  yoast_breadcrumb( '</p><p id="breadcrumbs">','</p><p>' );
}
?>
  <h1><?php echo $taxonomyslug->name; ?></h1>
<?php echo $description; ?>

</div>
</div>
</div>



<div class="row countrysec">


<?php

 $args = array('post_type' => 'trip',
     'tax_query' => array(
         array(
           'taxonomy' =>'region',
           'field' => 'slug',
           'terms' => $taxonomyslug->slug,
       ),
     ),
  );
  $loop = new WP_Query($args);
   if($loop->have_posts()) {  
  while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

  $term_list[] = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'activity', array('parent' => 0, "fields" => "all"));

  endwhile;
$ss='';
foreach ($term_list as  $value) {
  $ss.=($value[0]->name).",";
}

 $ss=explode(",",$ss);
 $ss1=array_values(array_filter(array_unique($ss)));
 $cc=count($ss1);
  for($l=0;$l<$cc;$l++){
 ?>



<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
 <h2 class="country-category">
 <span class="heading-title"><?php echo $ss1[$l];?></span>
</h2>
</div>

<?php

$args = array('post_type' => 'trip',
     'tax_query' => array(
         array(
           'taxonomy' =>'region',
           'field' => 'slug',
           'terms' => $taxonomyslug->slug,
       ),
     ),
  );


  $loop = new WP_Query($args);
  while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
  $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'tour_grid');
  $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'offers', array( 'fields' => 'all' ));
  $post_acf = get_fields($post->ID );
  $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'activity', array('fields' => 'all'));
  $terms_activity = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'activity_level', array('fields' => 'all' ));
  $i=0.5;
  //echo "<pre>";
  //print_r(get_fields());
?>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="Featured-item">
               <div class="Featured-item-img"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

                <?php the_post_thumbnail($size = 'post-thumbnail', $attr = '');?>

               </a><?php if (isset($terms[0]->name)){ ?><div class="offer"><span><?php echo $terms[0]->name; ?>% Off</span></div><?php } ?>
            </div>

               <div class="Featured-item-diss">                  
                  <ul class="list-inline">
                       <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $post_acf['days_number']; ?> Days" ><i class="fa fa-sun-o"></i>  <span><?php echo $post_acf['days_number']; ?> Days </span></a></li>
                           <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $post_acf['total_nights']; ?> Nights"><i class="fa fa-moon-o"></i> <span><?php echo $post_acf['total_nights']; ?> Nights</span> </a></li>

                             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $term_list[0]->name; ?>">
                            <i class="<?php 
                            if($term_list[0]->name=='Trek'){echo 'icon-hiking';}
                            if($term_list[0]->name=='Climb'){echo 'icon-mountain';}
                            if($term_list[0]->name=='Cycling'){echo 'icon-motorcycle';}
                            if($term_list[0]->name=='Discovery'){echo 'icon-europe';}
                            if($term_list[0]->name=='Family'){echo 'icon-family';}
                            if($term_list[0]->name=='Polar Cruise'){echo 'icon-cruise-ship';}
                            if($term_list[0]->name=='Wildlife'){echo 'icon-jungle';}
                            if($term_list[0]->name=='Winter'){echo 'icon-snow-ice';}
                            ?>"></i> <span><?php echo $term_list[0]->name; ?></span> 
                          </a></li>


                           <li><a href="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php if($terms_activity[0]->name!=''){echo $terms_activity[0]->name;}else{echo '';} ?>">

                            <?php if($terms_activity[0]->name=='Challenging'){?>
                            <i class="icon-level6"></i>
                            <?php }if($terms_activity[0]->name=='Easy'){?>
                            <i class="icon-level2"></i>
                            <?php }if($terms_activity[0]->name=='Moderate'){?>
                            <i class="icon-level4"></i>
                            <?php }if($terms_activity[0]->name=='Tough'){?>
                            <i class="icon-level8"></i>
                            <?php }if($terms_activity[0]->name==''){?>
                            <i class="icon-level1"></i>
                            <?php }?>

                          <span>  <?php if($terms_activity[0]->name!=''){echo $terms_activity[0]->name;}else{echo 'none';} ?></span> 


                          </a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <div class="Featured-item-title">
                     <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                  <?php the_field('sub_description');?>
                  </div>
                   <div class="price">
                     <h3>$<?php if (empty($terms[0]->name)){  echo $post_acf['regular_price'];  } else{ 
 echo $post_acf['regular_price']-($post_acf['regular_price']*($terms[0]->name))/100?><del>$<?php echo $post_acf['regular_price']; ?></del>
<?php } ?>
</h3>
                  </div>
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-danger">BOOK NOW</a>
               </div>
            </div>  
         </div>

<?php  //$j++;  
endwhile;  }
}
else{
  echo '<span><i class="fa fa-exclamation" aria-hidden="true"></i> Oops! Holiday Type was not found!</span>';
} wp_reset_postdata();
 ?>



</div>
</div>
</div>
</section> 





<?php get_footer();?>
```

pls anyone have idea where id did wrong?

Comment: Why are you doing s custom query? You should just be using the regular loop.

Comment: how can i display all post with terms in categorized way in single page??

Comment: You would use a custom template with custom queries, but that's not what `taxonomy-region.php` is for, and you wouldn't use `get_query_var( 'term' )` because it wouldn't be set. Honestly your code is very hard to parse. I can't really tell what you're trying to do.